# How to make 2 images on top of each other

Tags: html, css

So i'm trying to make 2 image to be on top of each other. The 1 needs always be at place 2. And number 3 always were it's now (i added it just incase) So i know there some answer out there how to do it bad I dont know how to apply them.[image]

```
HTML
<div class="container">
        <div class="HOMElinks">
            <div class="HOMElinks-big">
                <img src="img/link-big.jpg" width="450" height="325">
            </div>
            <div class="HOMElinks-small">
                <img src="img/link_basic.jpg" width="250" height="150">
            </div>

            <div class="HOMElinks-small">
                <img src="img/link_basic.jpg" width="250" height="150">
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
CSS
.HOMElinks {
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}

.HOMElinks-big {
    float: left;
}

.HOMElinks-small {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're floating both of your `.HOMElinks-small`.  By default they will line up next to each other if they have enough room.  An easy way to get around this would be to wrap them in a container and float that instead.

An unfortunate side effect of the above method is that it makes your `margin-bottom: 2.5%` have a different result compared to your original design.  This is because top and bottom margins (and padding to, for that matter) use the width of an element, not the height.  A way around that is to use viewport units instead.  In keeping with the width of the screen I used 2.5vw, where vw means viewport width.  This translates into 2.5% of the width of the window.

Here I used `.HOMElinks-small-group` as a container, vw for the margin, and changed the images to be sized by percentages so you could see the effect easier.

```css
.HOMElinks {
  margin-top: 2.5vw;
}
.HOMElinks-big {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}
.HOMElinks-small-group {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
.HOMElinks-small {
  margin-bottom: 2.5vw;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="HOMElinks">
    <div class="HOMElinks-big">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/325">
    </div>
    <div class=HOMElinks-small-group>
      <div class="HOMElinks-small">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/150">
      </div>
      <div class="HOMElinks-small">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/150">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNPQEV) as well.